# Can we write a part of a test with Selenium IDE and the other part with WebDriver and combine the two into one test?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I am new to selenium and am wondering if we can combine both Selenium IDE and WebDriver and write one test.

What I mean to ask is, can we use Selenium IDE for the easy tasks that we want to test and use WebDriver to test the part of the task that requires more robust tool and combine the two of them into one test?

Is it possible?

or is it that we can only work with one of them at a time?

I have tried to search for a solution to this question on internet but I only get results about a comparison between IDE and WebDriver.

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver is a tool you will have in the suite, but you do not have to use both together. They serve different functions altogether; they can absolutely be used together to make a great testing environment. For example, Selenium IDE can execute tests within the WebDriver server, speeding up execution.

Both tools can also be used for checking each other to an extent; using the different test cases can help you identify issues within the build in one or the other. It is most common to use them separately, one or the other. Selenium IDE and Selenium WebDriver are very different toolsets. Both can add to how you and your team handle testing, data, testing accessibility, and quality assurance.